# C++ Efficency of variable declaration

Tags: c++, performance, variables

I have a curiosity.
I would like to know if it is more efficient this code

```
int a(0);
for(int i=0;i!=10;++i){
    a=0;
    for(int j=0;j!=10;++j){
        // perform some operations on a
    }
}
```

or this code

```
for(int i=0;i!=10;++i){
    int a(0);
    for(int j=0;j!=10;++j){
        // perform some operations on a
    }
}
```

or it is exactly the some in term of performance. I understand that the answer may depend on the compiler and its inner optimization technique but I am curios to understand if there is any difference.

Thank you,
Marco.

Comment: Depends on the implementation. If the implementers have done their job there should be no difference and any deteriorations are going to be taken care of the optimizer.

Comment: +1 welcome on board ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any modern C++ compiler there's no difference what-so-ever.

Comment: +1 for answering the C++ question (in the former question, there is very much to read)